# memcached fork with regex deletion (delete_matched)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I am using memcached for a rails app at the moment. I need the delete_matched() feature, so I use an extra list with all the stored keys in it which I can match and delete one by one (someone wrote that already).

Problem is that it's not really working: some keys get not deleted from time to time - it really have no clue why, the code looks valid for me (and regexps are correct).

Is there an fork of memcached with this feature? I can't imagine why it's not implemented by default.

Comment: you [can't list all keys](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingFAQ#How_can_you_list_all_keys?). The memcached stance is against big slow commands like this.

Comment: You missunderstood, I don't want to list all the keys, I want to be able to delete keys by regular expressions (or similar). And I know that the default implamentation cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Redis with the `redis-rails` gem for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that and it's not implemented since it's slow. You should consider tagging the namespace. Here's the [explanation](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/).

If you still want to use regexes, refer to this blogpost:

http://quickleft.com/blog/faking-regex-based-cache-keys-in-rails

You could also use [dali-store-extensions](https://github.com/defconomicron/dalli-store-extensions) to achieve something like

```
 # in sweeper
 expire_fragment /.*sweep_me_up.*/
```